# How to save data from a new object in a nested resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking to create a new record within a nested resource in rails as according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

My model is:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

class Event < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
```

And I have declared my route as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :events do
        resources :entries
   end
```

What is the syntax for the entries controller for me to be able to create an entry on a link like `events/2/entries/new`. This is what I was trying:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @entry = Entry.new
 end


def create
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
    if @entry.save
        redirect_to @user
        flash.now[:info] = "Event Created"
    else
        render '/create'
        flash.now[:danger] = "Somthing went wrong"
    end
end


  def entry_params
        params.require(:event_id).permit(:siCard, :course)
    end

 end
```

On by `new.html.erb` I am using

```
<%= form_for(new_event_entry_path) do |f| %>.
```

But I cant get it to work as `No route matches [POST] "/events/1/entries/new"`
Many thanks

Comment: `No route matches [POST] "/events/1/entries/new"` @Simple Lime

Comment: form_for should be passed the instance variable `@entry`. e.g. `form_for(@entry)`. The instance variable should be built from the nesting e.g. `@event = Event.find(params[:event_id]); @entry = @event.entries.build` I have no idea how you are accessing "user" in this case but that should also be built in to the entry object.

Comment: With `<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>` I get a `NoMethodError in Entries#new`. Where `def new' contains the code you suggested. I fully understand your frustration as I am currently a beginner. Are there any good resources you can suggest to learn from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route you've provided in `form_for` does not accept POSTs. You've provided the route that renders the `new` page, not the route that accepts new records, which is the `create` route. For that, you'll want to use `event_entries_path(@event)` route helper.

With nested resources, the form_for's first argument should be an array: `<%= form_for([@event, @entry], ...`. Rails will intelligently choose the route you need based on whether the `@entry` is persisted or not.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that my `form_for` is wrong, are you saying that is should be replaced with `form_for([@event , @entry] ,event_entries_path(@event))`

Comment: Use `form_for([@event, @entry]) do`